# Как получить опции ip пакета в php/С++

Tags: php, curl, tcp-ip

Интересует опция `временных меток`, отправляемая в ip пакете. Можно ли каким то образом получить эти метки средствами `php` ? Попробовал `curl_getinfo($ch)` но не один из 26 параметров не похож на `timespan` временной метки т.к. они представляют собой  количество миллисекунд от полуночи по UTC. Ничего подобного в возвращаемой информации нет, если есть ткните.

Информация нужна для анализа загруженности сети, в идеале хорошо бы увидеть время в миллисекундах когда пакет был отправлен от сервера к клиенту. Если есть другие способы подобное реализовать, то прошу ткнуть в мануал.

**UPD** Добавил `С++` т.к. интерпретатор `php` написан на плюсах. Может есть способ получить опции пакета при помощи программы `C++`.

Comment: Это будет сложно. Придется создавать raw ip socket, вручную заполнить поля заголовка IP пакета, отослать его, принять raw пакет, и вручную посмотреть IP options.

Comment: @Zergatul да, понимаю и не прошу делать это за меня. Хотя бы подсказать куда двигаться.  raw ip socket создавать на php или на C++ а главное - реально ли получить время с точностью до миллисекунды когда пакет был отправлен из опций пакета ? временная метка вроде обязательный параметр, но может я ошибаюсь.

Comment: IP packet options необязательны, потому они и опции :) timestamp опция занимает 12 байт в заголовке, и было бы очень накладно в каждый пакет добавлять эту информацию, которая никогда не используется. С какой точностью там время - ну это от сервера зависит, кто прислал пакет. Я бы делал это на C++. В интернете есть примеры, как послать raw пакет, но примеров с приемом намного меньше (там вроде сложнее чем отослать).

Comment: Вы можете в любом трафик сниффере посмотреть IP пакеты, и проверить, если там эта опция. Если сервер не сконфигурирован специальным образом, то скорее всего ее нет

Comment: @Zergatul Значит надо скачать wireshark проверить есть ли эти опции в пакете ответа.

Comment: @Сергей, кстати, там же (в сорсах wireshark) можете посмотреть как читают пакеты через raw socket

Comment: @avp разобраться бы для начала где это ip опции в самом wireshark. )

Comment: @Сергей, я бы начал искать по обращениям к [Internet Header Length (IHL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямо из cURL такие данные посмотреть нельзя, но можно посмотреть со стороны с помощью обычных программ для просмотра трафика. Например, `tshark`, который, [как и PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/main), написан на C, если это почему-то важно. Если нужно чтобы программа была строго на C++, то такие тоже можно поискать. Будут ли они решать задачу также ясно и просто - вопрос открытый.

Запускаете прямо из PHP с помощью `exec` или `proc_open`, но лучше сначала потренироваться в консоли:

```
tshark -p -c 10 -e tcp.options.timestamp.tsval -e tcp.options.timestamp.tsecr -Tjson -Y 'tcp.option_kind == 8'
```

Получаете из стандартного выхода красивый JSON со всеми нужными значениями:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "packets-01001",
    "_type": "pcap_file",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "tcp.options.timestamp.tsval": ["2386387284"],
        "tcp.options.timestamp.tsecr": ["1871759056"]
      }
    }
  }

  ,
  { ....
```

Если нужна временная метка, можно добавить `-e frame.time`. Если нужно отобрать только входящие пакеты, только с определёнными свойствами, то фильтр легко составить по образцам пакетов в GUI Wireshark.

Наверное снимать такие метрики лучше в фоне, из `crontab` - сама процедура может занимать ощутимое время. Например, можно запускать саму команду выше с записью в файл, и через минуту запускать скрипт который этот файл будет читать и разбирать.

Чтобы использовать `tshark` без прав root кроме обычного шага при установке [нужно добавить себя в группу wireshark](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458762/how-to-enable-wireshark-without-running-as-root-in-trusty-14-04). В общем случае для запуска этих команд не нужно `sudo`.

Прямо из cURL такие данные посмотреть нельзя.

Comment: запускать во время отправки запроса и закрывать процесс когда получен ответ ? Я просто не уверен что эти метки вообще присутствуют в ответе сервера. Проверял через wireshark обнаружил некие временные метки, но они больше похожи на служебные самого wireshark - https://imgur.com/a/wBEvd3r

Comment: Обьясните подробнее куда идет вывод данных, и работает ли он все время пока сам скрипт висит в памяти ?

Comment: ничего не происходит. не ошибок не JSON. Добавил вывод в файл -` > ws_err.txt` файл 0byte

Comment: вам нужно запускать эту команду в фоне, из cron или в фоновом процессe

Comment: Не может быть что ничего не происходит. Это должна быть или какая-то ошибка (типа`tshark: command not found`), или сообщение о начале сбора данных (`Capturing on 'eth0'`)

Comment: Команда в моём ответе показывает именно те метки, которые вы просили из TCP options. [Не эти.](https://imgur.com/a/wBEvd3r)

Comment: Я понимаю что должен быт какой то вывод. Я использую `system("tshark -p -c 10 -e tcp.options.timestamp.tsval -e tcp.options.timestamp.tsecr -Tjson -Y 'tcp.option_kind == 8'");` что бы вывести результат вместо `exec` но не получаю нечего, даже сообщения об ошибке. далее проверюя запущенные процессы `system('ps -ef | grep "php"');` ничего нового не появляется.

Comment: `system()` не захватывает stderr, потому вы не видите ошибок. Попробуйте из консоли запустить. Зайдите по ssh на сервер или просто локально.

Comment: Попробовал в консоли - получил ошибку `Invalid -T parameter. It must be 'ps', 'text','pdml','psml' or 'field'`

Comment: Просто комманда в консоли  `sudo tshark` выводит захваченные пакеты. а вот скрипт `exec("sudo tshark", $arr_output);sleep(10);var_dump($arr_output);` выводит пустой массив, правильно ли я понимаю что не хватает привелегий ?

Comment: посмотрите вывод `id` в том и другом случае, возможно действительно не хватает прав; вообще всё должно работать без sudo - в конце ответа ссылка на инструкцию

Comment: `Invalid -T parameter` говорит о том что у вас старая версия tshark, или обновитесь, или используйте текстовый формат (его легко парсить)

Comment: Действительно, были проблемы в правах, добавил пользователя в sudoers и скрипт заработал. только не понял как в консоле остановить захват пакетов.

Comment: Никак не нужно, должно после 10 пакетов остановиться: `-c 10`

Comment: спасибо. один последний вопрос - опции временных меток яв-ся только опциями и возможно сервер их просто не возвращает, так ? т.е. если я не вижу timespan в захваченных пакетах это не обязательно значит что команда неправильная а может их просто не было изначально

Comment: Дело в том что я пытаюсь захватить пакеты именно так : `tshark -p -c 10 -e tcp.options.timestamp.tsval -e tcp.options.timestamp.tsecr -T fields` но в консоле ничего не выводится, просто 10 раз переход на новую строку. толи  этих меток нет толи я что то неправильно ввел.

Comment: Всё правильно, если у пакета нет полей, значит выводится пустота. Вам нужно добавить фильтр `-Y 'tcp.option_kind == 8'`

Comment: Спасибо, так получилось. Интересно, а сохраняются ли эти метки при использовании прокси!?  По идеи должны, только дополняются еще одной.